# Render vector letter in python

Tags: python, svg, rendering, vector-graphics

I would like to render a truetype letter to be used with the shapely module in python. (Say that I wish to make some morphologic operation on letters.)

Up to now, I managed to write a letter to a SVG file using cairo (see below). The letter is saved as a curve in the file header. The curve is basically what I need, but I believe there must be a much more elegant way to get the curve than to save, process and load a SVG file.

A second task is to load the curve in the format that shapely works with, but I think this can be done.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cairo
fo = file('test.svg', 'w')
WIDTH, HEIGHT  = 256, 256
surface = cairo.SVGSurface (fo, WIDTH, HEIGHT) ## Prepare a destination surface -> out to an SVG file!
ctx = cairo.Context (surface)
ctx.scale (WIDTH/1.0, HEIGHT/1.0) # Normalizing the canvas

ctx.move_to (0.1, 0.9)
ctx.set_font_size(1.)
character = "a"
ctx.show_text(character)

surface.finish()
```

Thank you in advance for your tips!

---

EDIT: I figured out that instead of show_text() one may draw a real curve using text_path(), but still I cannot read the points...

```
print ctx.text_path("b")
ctx.set_source_rgb (0.3, 0.2, 0.5) # Solid color
ctx.set_line_width (0.02)
ctx.stroke ()
```

---

EDIT2:
With a help of my colleague we managed to get a similar result as above. Using fontforge it is also possible to render a glyph and save it to SVG (in Bezier curves). It may be useful to somebody.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
## Outputs a glyph as a SVG, using FontForge (requires package 'python-fontforge')
import fontforge
f = fontforge.open("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf")
g = f["Aring"]
print g
g.export("orig.svg")
```

Optionally, one can already perform a morphologic dilation on the glyph before saving the SVG. (However, this is the only step of many that would be needed.)

```
g.stroke("circular", 100, "round", "round", "removeinternal")  ## morphologic dilation of the glyph
g.export("stroke.svg")
```

Also the precise bounding box can be established.

```
print "Stroked: g.boundingBox() =", g.boundingBox()
```

By the way, trying to write even trivial Inkscape plugins is quite frustrating, but I still believe it is the best way for the task.

Comment: Outline fonts are usually defined as splines. Postscript fonts use cubic Bézier curves, while TrueType fonts use quadratic B-splines. After a (quick) examination of the shapely manual, I see only points, line(string)s and polygons as supported geometric entities. So even if you manage to collect the control points from the letter outline, you'll still need to approximate the curves by linestrings.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to use [FreeType](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-py/) directly. The [`glyph-vector.py` example](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-py/source/browse/trunk/examples/glyph-vector.py) shows how to get at the glyph vector information.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I finally switched to writing an extension for inkscape, which provides not only the required operations in a python script, but also a simple GUI for settings.